# How can I parse Amazon S3 log files?

Tags: analytics, amazon-s3, logging

What are the best options for parsing Amazon S3 (Simple Storage) log files? I've turned on logging and now I have log files that look like this:

```
858e709ba90996df37d6f5152650086acb6db14a67d9aaae7a0f3620fdefb88f files.example.com [08/Jul/2010:10:31:42 +0000] 68.114.21.105 65a011a29cdf8ec533ec3d1ccaae921c 13880FBC9839395C REST.GET.OBJECT example.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2006/10/kitties_we_cant_stop_here_this_is_bat_country.jpg "GET /example.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2006/10/kitties_we_cant_stop_here_this_is_bat_country.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 - 32957 32957 12 10 "http://atlanta.craigslist.org/forums/?act=Q&ID=163218891" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.19) Gecko/2010031422 Firefox/3.0.19" -
```

What are the best options for automating the log files? I'm not using any other Amazon services other than S3.

Comment: Automating in what way? What information do you want to extract?

Comment: Something like Webalizer or AWStats or the like. Basic breakdowns by url, date, url, referrer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amazon recommends using AWStats and includes [instructions on how to set up an AWStats configuration file](http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/entry.jspa?externalID=2330). You will also need to set up some method to automate downloading the logs to where your AWStats installation is.

Personally I use cron to set off a Python script that uses [boto](http://code.google.com/p/boto/wiki/BotoS3Examples) to grab the files.

```
"""s3logDL.py

Downloads S3 logs and deletes old logs

Usage: python s3logDL.py"""

import sys
import os
from boto.s3 import Connection
import boto.s3

########################


########################

def main(argv):
    s3 = Connection('ACCESS_ID', 'PASSWORD')
    logsBucket = s3.get_bucket('logbucket')

    for b in logsBucket:
        #Download log
        print b.name
        key = logsBucket.get_key(b.name)
        fp = open("/PATH/TO/SAVE/POINT/" + b.name, "w")
        key.get_file(fp)

        #Delete log
        key.delete()

    exit(0)


########################

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv)
```

Answer (score 1):

We are about to launch [Qloudstat](http://qloudstat.com) which will give you analytics for your S3 account as a service.

Comment: It appears as though *you* are the registrant for the qloudstat.com domain - per our [FAQ](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion), it would be appreciated if you would edit your answer to disclose your affiliation to avoid downvotes or flags on your answer as spam.

Comment: No one likes spam Kocher!